# Javascript Select Child With Id Formatting

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Programming a ASP.net webapp to insert an entry into a database on form submit.

I've tried numerous configurations of find() and children() and they either

1) error

2) pass empty strings instead of what I type

This one errors like this:

[image]

Whats the correct way to select the individual children of myform?

**Javascript (the first block here is the code I'm asking about)**

```
var entry_array = [];

entry_array[0] = $('#myform').children('#01').css().text();
entry_array[1] = $('#myform').children('#02').css().text();
entry_array[2] = $('#myform').children('#03').css().text();
entry_array[3] = $('#myform').children('#04').css().text();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function () {
        alert("Function ran");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/SubmitEntry',  //(rec)= Controller's-name 
            //(recieveData) = Action's method name
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            data: { 'entry_array': entry_array },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
        });
        alert("Function finished running");
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitEntry(List<String> entry_array)
{

    String firstname = entry_array[0];
    String lastname = entry_array[1];
    String town = entry_array[2];
    String order = entry_array[3];

    knightsEntities db = new knightsEntities();

    int nextiD = 0;
    nextiD = db.Apprentenceship_Sheet.ToList().Last().id + 1;

    var newApprentenceship_Sheet = new Apprentenceship_Sheet();

    newApprentenceship_Sheet.first_name = firstname;
    newApprentenceship_Sheet.last_name = lastname;
    newApprentenceship_Sheet.hailed_town = town;
    newApprentenceship_Sheet.order = order;
    newApprentenceship_Sheet.id = nextiD;

    db.Apprentenceship_Sheet.Add(newApprentenceship_Sheet);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="~/scripts/custom.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <form id= "myform" method="post"> 
        First_name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="01" name="firstname"><br>
        Last_name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="02" name="lastname"><br>
        Town:<br>
        <input type="text" id="03" name="town"><br>
        Order:<br>
        <input type="text" id="04" name="order"><br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' id="05" name="Submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not binding to a model and post back that model (which can be done using 1/10 the code)? And why are you creating an array instead of an object?

Comment: Not sure why you're selecting CSS? How about selecting ".text();" not ".css.text()" for the array elements?

Comment: Why not using model binding ? you can send the serialized form in ajax.

Comment: To get the value of the input element, simply use `$('#01').val()`. But i strongly recommend you to use model binding and sending the serialized form via ajax (use jQuery serialize method)

Comment: Thanks guys i solved the problem using model binding....definitely a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of the text boxes directly by using **$('#01').val()**, or if you want refer it with reference to your form. You can use **$('#myform').find('#01').val()**. It will give the value of the text-box. Here is the jsfiddle for u.

```
$('#myform').find('#01').val()
$('#01').val()

  http://jsfiddle.net/71weztcn/
```

Comment: thank you!...this works but i went with model binding after learning about it